# Making an API call with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, create-react-app

Im aware this question has been asked in the past but with changes in react due to later versions I cannot seem to get it to work. I'm rather new to react, and have never worked with API's other than tutorials I've followed. I am trying to use "Movie database (IMDB Alternative) off of the site Rapidapi. As of now I am just trying to console.log the data so I can see what I want to pull and to make sure that I am correctly pulling the data, however, I cannot seem to get it working. I am trying to follow along with a tutorial that was recently on youtube, but cannot get it to work like I did in the tut. Here is my code thus far:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

useEffect(() => {
  getMovies();
}, []);

const getMovies = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/?page=1&r=json&s=Avengers%20Endgame", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": APP_HOST,
      "x-rapidapi-key": APP_KEY
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  console.log(data);
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Note: Everything assigned to the response variable is the code that the API gave me (I used the JavaScript fetch snippet). The APP_HOST and APP_KEY are from the site as well and I stored them inside those variables, which I am keeping hidden. I've looked at similar questions on this site and several tutorials online and on Youtube but nothing seems similar, and I still was unable to get it working. I am using create-react-app version 2.1.8 which is the same version I was using when I did the working tutorial. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `but cannot get it to work like I did in the tut.` Could you share what's not working? Is there an error, is `data` not logged to the console as expected?

Comment: Correct when I look at the inspector, it is telling me: "Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." Like I said I've never done this before so I am unsure of how to go about fixing that error which I also looked up. It is not logging to the console like I wanted it to.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is. Move the effect hook inside the function component.

Comment: @Quentin What would be moved in my code? Like I said, I'm doing this based off another tutorial and it is all exactly the same up to this point.

Comment: I said "the effect hook". You only have about 20 lines of code there. Which bit looks like it might be the effect hook? That bit.

Comment: @Quentin I would not have asked if I knew what you meant. I move the useEffect into the function but I am still getting an error. That step was not necessary when I did the tutorial which is essentially the same thing as mine, hence me asking. Not sure why you are answering if you're going to be vague when someone is confused. I cannot help that I am not of your level of programming, hence me asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in some comments, you'll have to move `useEffect` into your `App` function:

You're also mixing async/await and promises. Pick one.

Here's a version using async/await. (I added some state for showing your results or any errors):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

const getMovies = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
          'https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/?page=1&r=json&s=Avengers%20Endgame',
          {
            headers: {
              'x-rapidapi-host': APP_HOST,
              'x-rapidapi-key': APP_KEY
            }
          })
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`)
  }
  const data = await response.json()
  return data
}

const App = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState()
  const [error, setError] = useState()

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      setMovies(await getMovies())
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {error &&
      <span>{error}</span>}
      {movies &&
      <span>{movies.length} movies</span>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.**
These is the altercation you should made to your code.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {

useEffect(() => {
  getMovies();
}, []);

const getMovies = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/?page=1&r=json&s=Avengers%20Endgame", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": APP_HOST,
      "x-rapidapi-key": APP_KEY
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  console.log(data);
}

  return (
    <div className="App">

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```